# Limits of integral for Fourier Sine Transform.

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I've seen the Fourier Sine Transform defined in different ways.

Specifically:

$$F_s(\alpha) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(\alpha x)\space dx,$$

and:

$$F_s(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(\alpha x)\space dx$$

The difference is obviously that in the second case the lower limit is zero rather than negative infinity.

I don't know which one to use in my specific case: $f(x) = e^{-mx}$, $m >0$. Is there some constraint on the function in the second case that allows us to then increase the lower limit to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $m>0$ and $\alpha \ne0$, does the integral $\int_{-\infty }^0 \sin(\alpha x)e^{-mx}\,dx$ converge?

And for $x<0$, is $f(x)=0$?

Comment: The integral diverges because we end up with the exponent of infinity (and NOT its inverse) when we compute it? So it's just invalid and therefore we don't use it? And no, $f(x)$ can never be zero because it's an exponential function. Right?

Comment: One can define $f$ as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-mx}&x\ge 0\\\\0&,x<0\end{cases}$$Then, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin(\alpha x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(\alpha x)\,dx$$

Comment: Ok, but that seems like cheating. Is there a good reason why we should integrate from zero rather than $-\infty$?

Comment: Well, if $f=0$ when $x<0$, then we do integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  The idea is not necessarily "cheating."  In physics and engineering, causal functions are $0$ before time $t>0$ (i.e., there is no response before the system turns on at $t=0$)